# Does the Low Quality Post algorithm randomly pick posts and then randomly assign them?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

I ask because I just got an six-year-old post in my queue (the newest activity on the post was a comment from a year ago). I would think that that would have been purged a long time ago if the sensible thing was done and it started at the oldest post by date and move forward from there.

Comment: I think certain flags will cause even old posts to enter the queue.